# SQL Query w/ Net # Votes

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have this query:

```
SELECT   (COUNT (questions.id) / 10) AS totalPages,
          COUNT (DISTINCT answers.id) AS answers,
          COUNT (DISTINCT views.id) AS views,
                (SELECT(COUNT (if (votes.vote = 'up', 1, NULL)) - COUNT (if (votes.vote = 'down', 1, NULL)))
                   FROM   votes
                  WHERE   table = 'questions' AND tableId = questions.id) AS votes
FROM               questions
                LEFT JOIN
                   users
                ON questions.USER = users.id
             LEFT JOIN
                answers
             ON questions.id = answers.question
          LEFT JOIN
             views
          ON questions.id = views.question
       LEFT JOIN
          votes
       ON questions.id = votes.tableId AND votes.table = 'questions'
GROUP BY   questions.id
ORDER BY   questions.date DESC
LIMIT :limit
```

The topic of this post is about the `votes` field. It feels extremely unoptimized, and I want help in tackling a different method on how to implement it.

What it does is it takes all the results where the `vote`'s tableID is equal to the questions.id, and if the `vote` field within the `votes` table is up, it counts as one, otherwise subtract one (because obviously it would be down).

I've tried not using a subquery and trying

```
SUM( IF(votes.vote='up',1,-1) ) as votes
```

but with the grouping, the results become insanely wrong. I've also tried adding `DISTINCT` but that just made all the values -1 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need the subquery in the SELECT part. Try this:

```
SELECT 
    count(questions.id)/10 AS totalPages, 
    count(DISTINCT answers.id) as answers, 
    count(DISTINCT views.id) as views, 
    count(if(votes.vote='up', 1, null)) - count(if(votes.vote='down', 1, null))) as votes 
FROM 
    questions 
        LEFT JOIN users ON questions.user=users.id 
        LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.id=answers.question 
        LEFT JOIN views ON questions.id=views.question 
        LEFT JOIN votes ON questions.id=votes.tableId AND votes.`table`='questions' 
GROUP BY questions.id 
ORDER BY questions.date DESC 
LIMIT :limit
```